# pattern match and replace the string with if else loop

Tags: python, r, awk, sed

I have a file containing multiple lines starting with "1ECLI  H--- 12.345 .....". I want to remove a space between I and H and add R/S/T upon iteration of the H pattern. for eg. H810 if repeated in consecutive three lines, it should get added with a letter R, S (second iteration), T (third iteration). so it would be H810R. Any help will be appreciated.
text looks like below

```
1ECLI  H813   98   7.529   8.326   9.267
1ECLI  H813   99   7.427   8.470   9.251
1ECLI  C814  100   7.621   8.513   9.263
1ECLI  H814  101   7.607   8.617   9.289
1ECLI  H814  102   7.633   8.489   9.156
1ECLI  H814  103   7.721   8.509   9.305
1ECLI   C74  104   8.164   8.733  10.740
1ECLI  H74R  105   8.247   8.690  10.799
```

upon chage

```
1ECLI H813R   98   7.529   8.326   9.267
1ECLI H813S   99   7.427   8.470   9.251
1ECLI  C814  100   7.621   8.513   9.263
1ECLI H814R  101   7.607   8.617   9.289
1ECLI H814s  102   7.633   8.489   9.156
1ECLI H814T  103   7.721   8.509   9.305
1ECLI   C74  104   8.164   8.733  10.740
1ECLI  H74R  105   8.247   8.690  10.799
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why `H74R` doesn't get anything? What happens if H repeats more than 3 times?

Comment: It already has R... I want to add letters to the pattern "H digit digit digit" (H with 3 digits).

Comment: Removing the spaces isn't hard, but if you could answer PoGibas' questions, it would make answering much easier

Comment: Is there always going to be `H\d\d\d` 3 times consecutively ?

Comment: H with two digit and a letter R is fine and as per the required naming style. The H with three digit is missing with R/S/T letters.. I have to add it...

Comment: H\d\d\d 3 times consecution is not always present. it might be found two times only and thus need to add just R and S at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even below one can give desired output, if your real input file is same as what you have posted.

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("R,S,T",a,/,/)}f=$2~/^H[0-9]+$/{$2 = $2 a[++c]}!f{c=0}1' infile
```

**Explanation**

- `split("R,S,T",a,/,/)` - split string `"R,S,T"` by separator comma, and save in array `a`, so it becomes `a[1] = R, a[2] = S, a[3] = T`
- `f=$2~/^H[0-9]+$/` - `f` is variable, validate regexp `$2 ~ /^H[0-9]+$/`, which returns boolean status. if it returned `true` then variable `f` will be true, otherwise `false`
- `$2 = $2 a[++c]` if above one was true, then modify second field, so second field will have existing value plus array `a` value, corresponding to the index (`c`), `++c` is pre-increment variable
- `!f{c=0}` if variable `f` is false then reset variable `c`, not consecutive.
- `1` at the end does default operation that is print current/record/row, `print $0`. To know how awk works try, `awk '1' infile`, which will print all records/lines, whereas `awk '0' infile` prints nothing. Any number other than zero is *true*, which triggers the default behavior.

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
1ECLI  H813   98   7.529   8.326   9.267
1ECLI  H813   99   7.427   8.470   9.251
1ECLI  C814  100   7.621   8.513   9.263
1ECLI  H814  101   7.607   8.617   9.289
1ECLI  H814  102   7.633   8.489   9.156
1ECLI  H814  103   7.721   8.509   9.305
1ECLI   C74  104   8.164   8.733  10.740
1ECLI  H74R  105   8.247   8.690  10.799

$ awk 'BEGIN{split("R,S,T",a,/,/)}f=$2~/^H[0-9]+$/{$2 = $2 a[++c]}!f{c=0}1' infile
1ECLI H813R 98 7.529 8.326 9.267
1ECLI H813S 99 7.427 8.470 9.251
1ECLI  C814  100   7.621   8.513   9.263
1ECLI H814R 101 7.607 8.617 9.289
1ECLI H814S 102 7.633 8.489 9.156
1ECLI H814T 103 7.721 8.509 9.305
1ECLI   C74  104   8.164   8.733  10.740
1ECLI  H74R  105   8.247   8.690  10.799
```

If you want better formatting like `tab` or some other char as field separator, then you may use below one, modify `OFS` variable

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{split("R,S,T",a,/,/)}f=$2~/^H[0-9]+$/{$2 = $2 a[++c]}!f{c=0}{$1=$1}1'  infile
1ECLI   H813R   98  7.529   8.326   9.267
1ECLI   H813S   99  7.427   8.470   9.251
1ECLI   C814    100 7.621   8.513   9.263
1ECLI   H814R   101 7.607   8.617   9.289
1ECLI   H814S   102 7.633   8.489   9.156
1ECLI   H814T   103 7.721   8.509   9.305
1ECLI   C74     104 8.164   8.733   10.740
1ECLI   H74R    105 8.247   8.690   10.799
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly well. Only one query.. how would I get the tab set up as below..                                                                                                 1ECLI   C814  100   7.621   8.513   9.263
1ECLI H814R  101   7.607   8.617   9.289                                                                                                                                  instead of                                                                                                       1ECLI   C814    100 7.621   8.513   9.263
1ECLI   H814R  101 7.607   8.617  9.289

Comment: use `-v OFS="\t"`, and `{$1=$1}` awk will modify output field separator

Comment: 1ECLI   C814  100  7.621 8.513 9.263                                                       1ECLI H814R  101 7.607  8.617 9.289                                                       instead of                                                                                                         1ECLI C814   100  7.621 8.513 9.263                                                     1ECLI H814R 101 7.607  8.617 9.289                                                                   I am not able to show the leading and lagging tab pattern due to some reason..

Comment: how did you try ? can you post your command in comment, to make sure OFS is working, you may change `OFS='|'` for testing

Comment: awk -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{split("R,S,T",a,/,/)}f=$2~/^H[0-9]+$/{$2 = $2 a[++c]}!f{c=0}{$1=$1}1' test.in > test.out ,  OFS is working, I checked the way you suggested.

Comment: @amruta : then its correct only, to make sure do `od -c test.out`, you will see `\t` char

Answer (score 2):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  val[1]="R";
  val[2]="S";
  val[3]="T"
}
$2 !~ /^H[0-9]+/ || i==3{
  i=""
}
$2 ~ /^H[0-9]+$/ && /^1ECLI/{
  $2=$2val[++i]
}
1
'   Input_file  > temp_file  && mv  temp_file   Input_file
```

Adding explanation also for answer too as follows.

```
awk '
BEGIN{                        ##Starting BEGIN section of awk here.
  val[1]="R";                 ##creating an array named val whose index is 1 and value is string R.
  val[2]="S";                 ##creating array val 2nd element here whose value is S.
  val[3]="T"                  ##creating array val 3rd element here whose value is T.
}
$2 !~ /^H[0-9]+/ || i==3{     ##Checking condition if 2nd field does not start from H and digits after that OR variable i value is equal to 3.
  i=""                        ##Then nullifying the value of variable i here.
}
$2 ~ /^H[0-9]+$/ && /^1ECLI/{ ##Checking here if 2nd field value is starts from H till all digits till end AND line starts from 1ECLI string then do following.
  $2=$2val[++i]               ##re-creating value of 2nd field by adding value of array val whose index is increasing value of variable i.
}
1                             ##Mentioning 1 here, which means it will print the current line.
' Input_file   > temp_file  && mv  temp_file   Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: it is giving errors: awk: 1: unexpected character '''
awk: 14: unexpected character '''

Comment: @amruta, without letting me know which errors, I can't help you. Please let me know the errors? Also a GUESS on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk.

Comment: I did some minor changes and it worked but there is no addition of R S and T letters

Comment: But the changes are not done somehow... I am sorry you missed the last part of my text. The script ran but no changes done....

Comment: I got the output file but no changes were made.. as R, S, or T.

Comment: @amruta, did you try my edited version of command? Kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: Sorry. The code did not work... I did the changes as per your instructions. I am sorry as I am new to scripting... and did not know much. the code gives the same input file...let me know if I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes that `lines` is a list of strings representing a line in your file.

---

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

from collections import defaultdict
cntd = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
suffix = ['R', 'S', 'T']
newlines = []
for line in lines:
    try:
        kwd = line.split()[1]
    except IndexError:
        newlines.append(line)
        continue
    if kwd[0] == 'H' and kwd[-1].isdigit():
        sfx = suffix[cntd[kwd]]
        idx = line.index(kwd)
        nl = line[:idx -1] + kwd + sfx + line[idx + len(kwd):]
        # nl = line[:idx + len(kwd)] + sfx + line[idx + len(kwd):] # adjust formatting to your taste
        newlines.append(nl)
        cntd[kwd] += 1
    else:
        newlines.append(line)

with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(newlines)
```

Comment: I got following error.                                                                                               File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    for line in lines:
NameError: name 'lines' is not defined                                                                  My file name is test.dat and I put the code in test.py... should I change the 'lines' with 'test.dat'??

Comment: @amruta Read the first sentence in my answer. You are supposed to read all lines in your file into `lines`. Do you need help with this?

Comment: Thanks for reexplaining. but now it is giving me this error,   File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    kwd = line.split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range                                                                                          What does that mean?

Comment: It means that some of the lines in your input file do not have the structure shown in your post. For example, you may have empty lines. I will fix the code to skip those in a minute.

Comment: I did not get any output. Output file "test.log" is empty.

Comment: @amruta So, should I understand that you expect me to write a complete solution for you and you will not even make an effort to understand what this code is doing? Try printing `newlines` if you have a slightest idea of Python. If not - find some good tutorials.

Comment: Sorry. If you get offended. I am a new to scripting. also the code you provided did not make any changes as I wanted to have. Anyways, thank you for the information and sharing the code.

Comment: @amruta _"the code you provided did not make any changes as I wanted to have"_ You did not specify what you *wanted* to have in your original post. Learning how to read from a file or write to a file should be among the first things to learn in scripting. Anyway, I have added writing to a file for your pleasure.